# Swift Geocoder won't geocode address

Tags: swift, geocoding

When I pass an address string into `CLGeocoder.geocodeAddressString()`, the function never executes. When debugging, it never enters geocodeAddressString() and instead skips over. `location1` does contain a valid address.

```
func routeToLocation(location1: String, location2: String) {

    var location1Parsed = CLLocation()
    var location2Parsed = CLLocation()

    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(location1, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Error")
        }

        if let placemark = placemarks?.first{

            let coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

            location1Parsed = CLLocation(latitude: coordinates.latitude, longitude: coordinates.longitude)

            print(location1Parsed.coordinate.latitude)
            print(location1Parsed.coordinate.longitude)
        }
    })

    ... 

}
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: It must be that geocoder is failing to understand the address you're trying to create. I recommend if you know the coordinates of the address, try creating a a CLLocation from that and using reverse geocoder to see what place mark values it comes up with, and then try to match those when you do your forward geocoded.

Comment: What address are you trying to parse? I believe the above comment is the problem. The geocoder probably isn't parsing the correct address.